# NullReferenceException when calling FindPagesWithCriteria()

Tags: episerver, episerver-7

I'm calling `FindPagesWithCriteria(PageReference pageLink, PropertyCriteriaCollection criterias)` on an injected `DataFactory` and I'm getting a `NullReferenceException` in `DefaultPageCriteriaQueryService.GetProviderQueryService()`:

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   EPiServer.Core.DefaultPageCriteriaQueryService.GetProviderQueryService(ContentProvider
>   provider) +44
>   EPiServer.Core.DefaultPageCriteriaQueryService.FindPagesWithCriteriaInternal(PageReference
>   pageLink, PropertyCriteriaCollection criterias, String languageBranch,
>   ILanguageSelector selector, FindPagesWithCriteriaDelegate
>   findPagesDelegate) +293
>   EPiServer.Core.DefaultPageCriteriaQueryService.FindPagesWithCriteria(PageReference
>   pageLink, PropertyCriteriaCollection criterias, String languageBranch,
>   ILanguageSelector selector) +124
>   EPiServer.DataFactory.FindPagesWithCriteria(PageReference pageLink,
>   PropertyCriteriaCollection criterias) +115
>   ...

I've hooked up the Episerver symbol servers and stepped through the code, dee down in `DefaultPageCriteriaQueryService` I can see the `ContentProvider` being passed to `GetProviderQueryService()` is null leading to the NRE. The line calling this method is this:

```
case TypeOfSearch.Local:
      return findPagesDelegate(pageLink, tempCriteria, languageBranch, selector, this.GetProviderQueryService(this._providerManager.ProviderMap.GetDefaultProvider()));
```

with the culprit being that `_providerManager.ProviderMap.GetDefaultProvider()` returns null because `_providerManager.ProviderMap` is empty. I've never experienced this issue before and I can't find any relevant information about the ProviderMap if it should be initialised.

Why am I experiencing this issue? Why is my ProviderMap empty? Should my ProviderMap have a default provider?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can inject DataFactory since it's a singleton. You can however inject `EPiServer.Core.IPageCriteriaQueryService` instead which has the `FindPagesWithCriteria` method.

Answer (score 0):

As @Andreas alludes to, it's an issue with the dependency injection. I've added the following type bindings to my `IConfigurableModule` and everything works fine now:

```
cfg.For<DataFactory>().Use(() => DataFactory.Instance);
cfg.For<IContentRepository>().Use(() => DataFactory.Instance);
cfg.For<IContentLoader>().Use(() => DataFactory.Instance);
```